# No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Onclick insert button it will through an error, and say no mapping exist for exeute non query commands
After Entering data in form when i click on insert button then it through an exception that no mapping exists and indicating to execute non query

On button click event

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Usercreateorupdate", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtname.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", txtfname.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MName", txtmname.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", radiogender.SelectedValue);//radiobuttonlist
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobileno",textmobile.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address",textaddress.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtemail.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtdob.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textpassword.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", drpcountry.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", drpstate.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", drpcity.SelectedValue);//dropdown
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pincode", textpincode.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", courselist.Items);//checkboxlist
            int i=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (i > 0)
            {
                lblsuccessmsg.Text = "Inserted Successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                lblerrormsg.Text = "Failed";
            }
```

```
   And Connection string
```

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DIVYANSHU\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=allinone; Integrated Security=True;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

Stored Procedure for insert

```
USE [allinone]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Usercreateorupdate]    Script Date: 01-Oct-19 2:36:11 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Usercreateorupdate]
@ID int,
@Name varchar(50),
@FName varchar(50),
@MName varchar(50),
@Gender varchar(50),
@MobileNo int,
@Address varchar(50),
@Emailid varchar(50),
@DOB varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@Country varchar(50),
@State varchar(50),
@City varchar(50),
@Pincode varchar(50),
@Course varchar(50)
AS 
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO regis(Name,FName,MName,Gender,MobileNo,Address,Emailid,DOB,Password,Country,State,City,Pincode,Course) VALUES(@Name,@FName,@MName,@Gender,@MobileNo,@Address,@Emailid,@DOB,@Password,@Country,@State,@City,@Pincode,@Course)
   END
```

Comment: Is ID a primary key?  It looks like you are missing ID and a table with a Primary key must have the key.  You are missing the key.

Comment: Yes and identity also

Comment: No sure what you mean by identity.  Only the primary key is needed when writing to database, other fields are optional unless the field is specified as "not null".  Do you know how to fix issue?

Comment: I mean identity specification , and identity increment whenever we insert new data it take id by itself by this we can fix "not null " error also.